# Counting month name occurrences in R dataframe column

Tags: r, string, tidyverse

I have a dataframe like this

```
from <- c('Bob', 'Matt', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Matt', 'Bob', 'Matt')
subject <- c('See you in June', 'Funny cat video', 'Plans for December', 'Re: Plans for December', 'Re:Re: Plans for December','November sales', 'Out of office in November')

df <- data.frame(from, subject)

  from                   subject
1  Bob           See you in June
2 Matt           Funny cat video
3  Bob        Plans for December
4  Bob    Re: Plans for December
5 Matt Re:Re: Plans for December
6  Bob            November sales
7 Matt Out of office in November
```

I want to find month name occurrences as strings in `subject` based on built-in `month.name` vector

```
 [1] "January"   "February"  "March"     "April"     "May"       "June"      "July"     
 [8] "August"    "September" "October"   "November"  "December"
```

then sum them by `from` value and by month. I would like to get results like these:

```
from    month counts
1  Bob     June      1
2  Bob November      1
3 Matt November      1
4  Bob December      2
5 Matt December      1
```

My guess is that I need to use `str_count` like below, but I'm not sure how to also count by the names in `from`.

```
df %>%
  mutate(counts = str_count(subject, month.name)
```

Comment: First create your month column using str_extract, then groupby, then summarise

Comment: Is there a possibility that multiple months can occur in the same string?

Answer (score 1):

one more solution

```r
library(tidyverse)
from <- c('Bob', 'Matt', 'Bob', 'Bob', 'Matt', 'Bob', 'Matt')
subject <- c('See you in June', 'Funny cat video', 'Plans for December', 'Re: Plans for December', 'Re:Re: Plans for December','November sales', 'Out of office in November')

df <- data.frame(from, subject)
df %>% 
  group_by(from) %>% 
  mutate(month = map(strsplit(subject, split = " "), ~intersect(.x, month.name))) %>% 
  unnest(month) %>% 
  count(from, month)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#> # Groups:   from [2]
#>   from  month        n
#>   <chr> <chr>    <int>
#> 1 Bob   December     2
#> 2 Bob   June         1
#> 3 Bob   November     1
#> 4 Matt  December     1
#> 5 Matt  November     1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

using **data.table**

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, list(from, month = unlist(tstrsplit(subject, split = " ")))][month %in% month.name][, .N, by = list(from, month)]
#>    from    month N
#> 1:  Bob November 1
#> 2:  Bob December 2
#> 3:  Bob     June 1
#> 4: Matt December 1
#> 5: Matt November 1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution, ising `str_extract_all` and then some work with lists in a data.frame:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(months = list(str_extract_all(subject, month.name))) %>%
    unnest(months) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    filter(length(months) > 0) %>%
    unnest(months) %>%
    count(from, months)

#   from  months       n
# 1 Bob   December     2
# 2 Bob   June         1
# 3 Bob   November     1
# 4 Matt  December     1
# 5 Matt  November     1
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `regmatches` + `subset` + `aggregate`

```
aggregate(
  n ~ from + months,
  subset(
    transform(
      df,
      months = unlist(
        replace(
          u <- regmatches(subject, gregexpr(paste0(month.name, collapse = "|"), subject)),
          lengths(u) == 0,
          NA
        )
      ),
      n = 1
    ),
    !is.na(months)
  ), sum
)
```

gives

```
  from   months n
1  Bob December 2
2 Matt December 1
3  Bob     June 1
4  Bob November 1
5 Matt November 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R solution:

```
subset(
  aggregate(ctr ~ from + months_,
   transform(
     data.frame(do.call(rbind, Map(
       function(y, z) {
         cbind(from = y, months_ = z)
       },
       df$from,
       apply(do.call(rbind, lapply(month.name, function(w) {
         grepl(w, df$subject)
       })), 2, function(x) {
         if (sum(x) == 0) {
           ""
         } else{
           month.name[x]
         }
       })
     )),
     stringsAsFactors = FALSE), ctr = 1
   ), sum), 
  months_ !=  "")
```